# C#. Как правильно написать конвертацию одного абстрактного типа к другому?

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода

**Предисловие.** Чтобы как-то описать проблему я написал консольное приложение (см. код ниже).

**Суть задачи.** Пусть есть два протокола передачи сообщений: `St` и `Gv`. Есть два абстрактных типа:

- StMessage
- GvMessage

Нужно реализовать конвертацию сообщений типа `StMessage` в `GvMessage`. Реализации `StMessage` содержат уникальный набор полей для своего типа сообщений. После конвертации необходимо вывести сообщение в консоли.

Вот, что у меня получилось. Кода достаточно много, для удобства разбил на регионы, поэтому лучше посмотреть его в редакторе кода. **Код**:

```
using System;

namespace TestHelloWorld.ConsoleApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LaunchTestOfStatusMessageConverting();
            LaunchTestOfSpeedMessageConverting();
        }

        private static void LaunchTestOfStatusMessageConverting()
        {
            var stMessage = new StMessageStatus
            {
                Status = "Pending"
            };

            var converter = GetConverterForMessage(stMessage);
            var gvMessage = converter.Convert(stMessage);

            var printer = new ConsoleMessagePrinter();
            printer.PrintMessage(gvMessage);
        }

        private static void LaunchTestOfSpeedMessageConverting()
        {
            var stMessage = new StMessageSpeed
            {
                Speed = 42
            };

            var converter = GetConverterForMessage(stMessage);
            var gvMessage = converter.Convert(stMessage);

            var printer = new ConsoleMessagePrinter();
            printer.PrintMessage(gvMessage);
        }

        private static IMessageConverter GetConverterForMessage(StMessage stMessage)
        {
            switch (stMessage.MessageType)
            {
                case StMessageType.Speed:
                    return new SpeedMessageConverter();
                case StMessageType.Status:
                    return new StatusMessageConverter();
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }

    #region [ GvMessages ]

    public enum GvMessageType
    {
        Speed,
        Status
    }

    public abstract class GvMessage
    {
        public abstract GvMessageType MessageType { get; }
    }

    public class GvMessageSpeed : GvMessage
    {
        public override GvMessageType MessageType => GvMessageType.Speed;

        public int Speed { get; set; }
    }

    public class GvMessageStatus : GvMessage
    {
        public override GvMessageType MessageType => GvMessageType.Status;

        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion


    #region [ StMessages ]
    
    public enum StMessageType
    {
        Speed,
        Status
    }

    public abstract class StMessage
    {
        public abstract StMessageType MessageType { get; }
    }

    public class StMessageSpeed : StMessage
    {
        public override StMessageType MessageType => StMessageType.Speed;

        public int Speed { get; set; }
    }

    public class StMessageStatus : StMessage
    {
        public override StMessageType MessageType => StMessageType.Status;

        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion


    #region [ Converters ]

    public interface IMessageConverter
    {
        GvMessage Convert(StMessage stMessage);
    }

    public class StatusMessageConverter : IMessageConverter
    {
        public GvMessage Convert(StMessage stMessage)
        {
            var stMessageStatus = stMessage as StMessageStatus;
            if (stMessageStatus == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Message is not of {nameof(StMessageStatus)} type", nameof(stMessage));
            }

            var gvMessageStatus = new GvMessageStatus
            {
                Status = stMessageStatus.Status
            };

            return gvMessageStatus;
        }
    }

    public class SpeedMessageConverter : IMessageConverter
    {
        public GvMessage Convert(StMessage stMessage)
        {
            var stMessageSpeed = stMessage as StMessageSpeed;
            if (stMessageSpeed == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Message is not of {nameof(StMessageStatus)} type", nameof(stMessage));
            }

            var gvMessageSpeed = new GvMessageSpeed
            {
                Speed = stMessageSpeed.Speed
            };

            return gvMessageSpeed;
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region [ Message printers ]

    public interface IMessagePrinter
    {
        void PrintMessage(GvMessage message);
    }

    public class ConsoleMessagePrinter : IMessagePrinter
    {
        public void PrintMessage(GvMessage message)
        {
            string messageAsText;
            switch (message.MessageType)
            {
                case GvMessageType.Speed:
                    var speedMessage = (GvMessageSpeed) message;
                    messageAsText = $"Gv speed message. Speed={speedMessage.Speed}";
                    break;
                case GvMessageType.Status:
                    var statusMessage = (GvMessageStatus)message;
                    messageAsText = $"Gv status message. Status={statusMessage.Status}";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(messageAsText);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Не могу понять, насколько правильно я решал эту задачу с помощью средств языка C#. Мне кажется, здесь что-то не так. Как минимум, мне не нравятся обратные преобразования объекта из базового типа в конкретный.

Прошу проинспектировать мой подход к решению данной задачи и, если что-то не так, предложить свой вариант решения.

Comment: Нужны ли два перечисления: `GvMessageType` и `StMessageType`, - у которых одинаковые значения? Нельзя ли их заменить одним общим? | Зачем вообще эти перечисления, если есть строгие типы? Свойства `MessageType` дублируют тип самих классов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov одним общим - точно нет, потому что по сути это разные типы сообщений. Gv и St должны быть независимы друг от друга. А вот по поводу "убрать MessageType совсем": я его внедрял только ради того, чтобы при выборе конвертера смотреть на это поле и через switch-case выбрать нужный конвертер

Comment: Я просто не могу понять, как я могу грамотно, без дублирования кода, описать этот процесс конвертации. Все, что приходит в голову - оценивать реальный тип объекта через множество if конструкций...

Comment: Кстати, можно использовать C# 8? Возможно, паттерн-матчинг будет уместен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можно, но не желательно. Я хотел бы узнать базовый подход к такого рода конвертации. Может быть, я ошибся с иерархией классов и интерфейсов. Наверняка уже есть шаблон проектирования, который применим здесь

Comment: Производительность важна? Можно сильно упростить код, заюзав `dynamic`. Но это **очень** медленно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не особо важна, но все же ищу типобезопасное решение :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а никак сюда нельзя прикрутить generic?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а чем  паттерн-матчинг тут от switch/набора ифов принципиально отличается тут?

Comment: @Grundy - просто чуть короче будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, вполне можно убрать свойство `MessageType`. Ведь оно, по сути, дублирует тип самих классов.

После удаления этого свойства в шести классах, меняем некоторые методы.

Код двух изменённых методов. Вместо свитча по свойству используется проверка по типу самого объекта.

```
private static IMessageConverter GetConverterForMessage(StMessage stMessage)
{
    switch (stMessage)
    {
        case StMessageSpeed _:
            return new SpeedMessageConverter();
        case StMessageStatus _:
            return new StatusMessageConverter();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

```
public void PrintMessage(GvMessage message)
{
    string messageAsText;
    switch (message)
    {
        case GvMessageSpeed speedMessage:
            messageAsText = $"Gv speed message. Speed={speedMessage.Speed}";
            break;
        case GvMessageStatus statusMessage:
            messageAsText = $"Gv status message. Status={statusMessage.Status}";
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(messageAsText);
}
```

---

Предлагаю следующий вариант с применением диспетчеризации с помощью `dynamic`.

Класс-конвертер:

```
public class MessageConverter
{
    public GvMessage Convert(StMessage stMessage)
    {
        return Convert((dynamic)stMessage);
    }
    private GvMessage Convert(StMessageStatus messageStatus)
    {
        return new GvMessageStatus
        {
            Status = messageStatus.Status
        };
    }
    private GvMessage Convert(StMessageSpeed messageSpeed)
    {
        return new GvMessageSpeed
        {
            Speed = messageSpeed.Speed
        };
    }
}
```

Используем его в методах `LaunchTest*`:

```
var converter = new MessageConverter();
var gvMessage = converter.Convert(stMessage);
```

---

Ещё одно предложение. Перегружаем метод `ToString`:

```
public class GvMessageSpeed : GvMessage
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"Gv speed message. Speed={Speed}";
}
public class GvMessageStatus : GvMessage
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"Gv status message. Status={Status}";
}
```

Это позволяет сильно упростить класс принтера.
А в принципе можно его и совсем удалить.

```
public class ConsoleMessagePrinter : IMessagePrinter
{
    public void PrintMessage(GvMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

---

---

Самый простой вариант получается, если объекты `StMessage` осведомлены о существовании объектов другого типа. Тогда прямо на них можно возложить обязанности конвертации. При этом мы полностью избавляемся от дополнительных классов конвертеров.

```
using System;

namespace TestHelloWorld.ConsoleApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LaunchTestOfStatusMessageConverting();
            LaunchTestOfSpeedMessageConverting();
        }
        private static void LaunchTestOfStatusMessageConverting()
        {
            StMessage stMessage = new StMessageStatus { Status = "Pending" };

            GvMessage gvMessage = stMessage.ToGvMessage();

            var printer = new ConsoleMessagePrinter();
            printer.PrintMessage(gvMessage);
        }
        private static void LaunchTestOfSpeedMessageConverting()
        {
            StMessage stMessage = new StMessageSpeed { Speed = 42 };

            GvMessage gvMessage = stMessage.ToGvMessage();

            var printer = new ConsoleMessagePrinter();
            printer.PrintMessage(gvMessage);
        }
    }

    public abstract class GvMessage
    {
        public abstract string GetString();
    }
    public class GvMessageSpeed : GvMessage
    {
        public int Speed { get; set; }
        public override string GetString() => $"Gv speed message. Speed={Speed}";
    }
    public class GvMessageStatus : GvMessage
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public override string GetString() => $"Gv status message. Status={Status}";
    }

    public abstract class StMessage
    {
        public abstract GvMessage ToGvMessage();
    }
    public class StMessageSpeed : StMessage
    {
        public int Speed { get; set; }

        public override GvMessage ToGvMessage() => new GvMessageSpeed { Speed = Speed };
    }
    public class StMessageStatus : StMessage
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public override GvMessage ToGvMessage() => new GvMessageStatus { Status = Status };
    }

    public interface IMessagePrinter
    {
        void PrintMessage(GvMessage message);
    }
    public class ConsoleMessagePrinter : IMessagePrinter
    {
        public void PrintMessage(GvMessage message) => Console.WriteLine(message.GetString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndreiKhotko - см. обновления

Comment: Идея с возложением обязанности конвертации на класс сообщения - мне очень нравится. Только наверно я бы сделал это через реализацию интерфейса. Идея в том, что я хочу, чтобы `Gv` и `St` были отделными сборками. А интерфейс конвертации - в сборке, которая использует две эти библиотеки. Это нужно для того, чтобы `St` сборка ничего не знала про `Gv` сборку и наоборот

Comment: Хотя нет. Так, как я выше написал, не получится

Comment: @AndreiKhotko - да, если эти классы в разных сборках/слоях, то нужен отдельный класс конвертера, как и было изначально.

Answer (score 2):

Если протоколы St и Gv ничего не знают друг о друге - то, как бы вы ни исхитрялись, вы не сможете написать такой конвертер, который бы работал после обновления любого из протоколов. Стоит добавить в один из протоколов новое сообщение - и конвертер придётся тоже обновлять, и это верно для любого конвертера.

Самый простой вариант конвертера выглядит вот так:

```cs
public static StMessage ToSt(this GvMessage src) => src switch {
    GvMessageStatus msg => new StMessageStatus { Status = msg.Status },
    GvMessageSpeed msg => new StMessageSpeed { Speed = msg.Speed },
    _ => throw new ArgumentException(...),
};
```

Единственный недостаток подобного подхода - компилятор не сможет проследить что вы обработали все возможные сообщения. Если вам это важно - придётся применить паттерн visitor, тут придётся уже написать заметно больше кода:

```cs
public interface GvMessageVisitor<R> {
    R VisitStatus(string status);
    R VisitSpeed(int speed);
}

partial class GvMessage {
    public abstract R Visit<R>(GvMessageVisitor<R> visitor);
}

partial class GvMessageStatus {
    public override R Visit<R>(GvMessageVisitor<R> visitor) => visitor.VisitStatus(Status);
}

partial class GvMessageSpeed {
    public override R Visit<R>(GvMessageVisitor<R> visitor) => visitor.VisitSpeed(Speed);
}

// ...

class GvToStVisitor : GvMessageVisitor<StMessage> {
    public StMessage VisitStatus(string status) => new StMessageStatus { Status = status };
    public StMessage VisitSpeed(int speed) => new StMessageSpeed { Speed = speed };
}

public static StMessage ToSt(this GvMessage src) => src.Visit(new GvToStVisitor());
```

Теперь ваш конвертер не сможет скомпилироваться если вы не учли все возможные сообщения.

---

Наконец, последний из предлагаемых мною подходов. Раз уж у вас есть два очень похожих протокола - почему бы не попытаться выделить предметную область и не создать её модель, сделав оба протокола зависимыми от этой модели, а не наоборот?

При этом преобразование из транспортной модели в основную будет происходить напрямую, а обратное - через тот же visitor:

```cs
public interface Message {
    R Visit<R>(MessageVisitor<R> visitor);
}

public interface MessageVisitor<R> {
    R VisitStatus(string status);
    R VisitSpeed(int speed);
}

public sealed class SpeedMessage : Message {
   public int Speed { get; }

   public SpeedMessage(int speed) {
       Speed = speed;
   }

   public R Visit<R>(MessageVisitor<R> visitor) => visitor.VisitSpeed(Speed);
}

// ...

partial class GvMessage {
    public abstract Message ToMessage();
}

partial class GvMessageSpeed {
    public override Message ToMessage() => new SpeedMessage(Speed);
}

partial class GvMessageStatus {
    public override Message ToMessage() => new StatusMessage(Status);
}

public class GvMessageFactory : IMessageVisitor<GvMessage> {
    public GvMessage VisitSpeed(int speed) => new GvSpeedMessage(speed);
    public GvMessage VisitStatus(string status) => new GvStatusMessage(status);
}
```

При таком подходе, вполне возможно, вам могут даже не понадобиться отдельные классы для протокола, достаточно будет правильного (де)сериализатора.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Полезная информация на будущее. Для моей задачи не нужна такая серьезная поддержка обновлений протоколов, потому что сервис, который я пишу, будет обслуживать определенное устройство с определенным протоколом, который для данной модели никогда не изменится